# Adding context paths to ELK log analytics?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I'm looking to install the ELK stack on my application server by following [the instructions here:](https://logz.io/learn/complete-guide-elk-stack/#installing-elk)

I can see you can then access the various ELK services on localhost via certain ports. Is there a way for me add context paths for the services. Then I can configure my apache to point the various context paths to the different ports for the different services?

Also as a separate question is there a way to set this up so these can be publicly accessible from a url different to the one that is associated with the public ip of the vm? I'm using Azure

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it’s possible, but without knowing what you have tried so far it’s hard to provide advice.

Comment: I just want to know how to configure the context path on the application side? Do you know how to do that?